# Removing forward slashes after a particular subfolder section in a URL address

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a networking site that has member data organised into subfolders. To access the data, a user would need to go to something like:-

**www.domain.com/members/so/me/on/esfolder**

My question is, can I use a function in the .htaccess file to allow users to visit the same page by just typing:-

**www.domain.com/members/someonesfolder**

I have read up on the Rewrite syntax but struggling to understand how to do this. It is simply a case of removing the forward slashes after a particular point.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself after a non-stop mess around lasting several hours... For those who might want to know, here is the code I used...

**RewriteRule ^members/([A-Za-z0-9]{1,2})([A-Za-z0-9]{1,2})([A-Za-z0-9]{1,}) members/$1/$2/$3/ [L]**

In the above, there is just three sub-folder drill downs (which is what I have decided to do rather than the four in my original question).

Hope this helps someone else!